# Android ImageView Resize Issue

Tags: android, layout, imageview, zooming

Inside the ImageView there is a picture.

I wish to zoom in the picture by adjusting the width and length of the ImageView.

Codes are listed here:

```
 mZoomInBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            double zoomInRatio = (mZoomInBar.getProgress() / 25.00d) + 1;
            mMapBed.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(zoomInRatio * mapOriginalHeight);
            mMapBed.requestLayout();
            mMapBed.getLayoutParams().width = (int)(zoomInRatio * mapOriginalWidth);
            mMapBed.requestLayout();
        }
    });
```

The height is now zoom-able, but width don't even change a bit. I don't know why.

By the way, the xml part of the ImageView looks like this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/nycsubway"
                android:id="@+id/map">
            </ImageView>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
```

Any idea?  Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

I've found out what the problem is: the layout.

If I put HorizontalScrollView before ScrollView, Width IS zoom-able, but Height is NOT zoom-able; ScrollView before HorizontalScrollView, Height IS zoom-able, but Width is NOT.

How to solve this issue...?

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

Turns out, the image should be displayed using android:src, and android:adjustViewBounds="true" required in xml.

Comment: you probably dont need to call requestLayout twice, you can just call it once. Also check to print the valeus of widths if there are any issues with double to int conversion.

Comment: I tried to call just once, but doesn't help.

Comment: what are the values for width generated? Also, did you try by setting the mMapBed.setlayoutParams() ?

Comment: Width is a number around 1500. I will try Setlayoutparams when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_connt"
    >
```